# How can I find the SQL statement that created a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

So I forgot what a column in a view actually is, and the name I gave it is too vague.  Can I find the statement used to construct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname will do it in MySQL 5+